# spark submit failed when reading from Avro files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

When trying to run my spark jar using spark-submit, I got an error.
The line that causes it

```
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/home/user/samples/events")
```

the stacktrace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat not found
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:529)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:301)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:156)
```

can't understand what is missing and why it calls ORC format?
I make sure that the class exists in spark/jar folder 
"org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/orc/OrcFileFormat"

Spark version: 2.3.2

Thanks :-)

Comment: can you ensure if the underlying files at path `/home/user/samples/events` are in avro format ?

Comment: yes, I even tried to load single avro file, same result

Comment: can you add avro jar to classpath and do `spark.read.avro("path")` instead